# Website not loading correctly on iPad iOS 8

Tags: ios, ipad

Worked a week or two, then messed up with this error at the top of the browser and then kept reloading.

```
"A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded"
```

iPhone is OK and all other browsers are OK.

Comment: Can you specify website name here? If it is not private.

Answer (score 1):

Found that someone had added

```
position: fixed;
```

to a search sidebar to keep it next to the items on the page as the user scrolls. Removing just that line made it work again.

Lots of results on Google for this with no solution, and it only seems to affect iOS8 on iPad.

Not sure if other things are involved e.g. this page has react components on it.